# React function doesn't construct correct array

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing some weird behavior in my code.

I have the following function:

```
const generateDefaultDataForModel = (data: any) => {
        const numBlocks = data && Object.keys(data).length > 0 ? data[Object.keys(data)[0]].length : 3;
        console.log("numBlocks", numBlocks);

        const defaultWeight = 1 / Object.keys(originalWeights).length;
        console.log("defaultWeight", defaultWeight);

        const defaultData = Array.from({ length: numBlocks }, () => [defaultWeight, true]);
        console.log("defaultData", defaultData);

        const test = Array.from({ length: numBlocks }, () => [defaultWeight, true]);    
        console.log("test", test);

        return test;
    };
```

Basically the idea is that it creates some default data for me to use. When I run this via an onClick event I can see the console outputs which in the first one (`numBlocks`) gives me 3. `defaultWeight` gives me 0.9. However, when I try to create `defaultData` I jsut get an array like: `[[0, true], [0, true], [0, true]]`.

However, in the next line with `test` I do the exact same thing, but t hat output is: `[[0.9, true], [0.9, true], [0.9, true]]`

At first I thought I had a reused variable name, but no. Even if I change the name `defaultData` to something weird, same thing happens. If I then comment out the `defaultData` line, then `test` doesn't output the correct data any more.

Even if I hardcode the value of `numBlocks` and `defaultWeight` I get the same issue.

I have no idea what is going on. It seems like it should be so simple, but it's giving me a bit of a head scratch right now.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

When I call this I have now tried this:

```
const newCurrentWeights = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentWeights));

generateDefaultDataForModel(originalWeights);
newCurrentWeights[model] = generateDefaultDataForModel(originalWeights);
```

In this case `currentWeights` have the structure:

```
{key: {key: [value, bool]}}
```

So here the `generateDefaultDataForModel(originalWeights)` alone gives the right output, however, when it is used when I set the newCurrentWeights[model] the output is wrong.

I have no idea if this makes it easier to understand :)

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: `const test = Array.from({ length: numBlocks }, () => [defaultWeight, true]);` will create an Array of numBlocks length, all the same with `[defaultWeight, true]` being the data - it's what you wrote - `defaultWeight` is a single value ... what output were you expecting instead? P.S. nothing at all to do with reactjs, you may be "using" reactjs in some capacity, but not here ... just plain ol' javascript here

Comment: So the issue is that `test` contains `[0.9, true]` while `defaultData` has `[0, true]`, even though the array generation code for both is the same? I can't see how this code would be doing that, unless there's something between creating `defaultData` and `test` that is doing something that's shown here? Are you able to create a reproducible example maybe?